# can not access email via gmail since using cloudflare

Tags: gmail, cloudflare

in cloudflare

I set

```
MX mydomain.com mail handled by mail.mydomain.com with priority 10 Automatic
```

in gmail, I set pop server

```
mail.mydomain.com port 110
```

but it reports error

```
There was a problem connecting to mail.mydomain.com
```

your comment welcome

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you don't have the proper mail and MX records configured for the domain. Please open a support ticket & CloudFlare support can review your zone file. Please be sure to include the mail records your provider wants you to have so we can compare it against your current zone file.